# Data structure for managing contact-collision info between particles

Tags: c++, unordered-map, particle-system

I am performing some particle simulations in C++ and I need to keep a list of contacts info between particles. A contact is actually a data struct containing some data related to the contact. Each particle is identified with a unique ID. Once a contact is lost, it is deleted from the list. The bottleneck of the simulation is computing the force (a routine inside the contacts), and I have found an important impact on the overall performance according to the actual way the contact list is organised.

Currently, I am using a c++ unordered_map (hash map), whose key is a single integer obtained from a pair function applied over the two unique IDS of the particles, and the value is the contact itself.

I would like to know if there is a better approach to this problem (organising efficiently the list of contacts while keeping the info of the particles they are related with) since my approach is done just because I read and found than a hash map is fast for both insertion and deletion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to look-up and remove specific contacts? I would simply fill up an `std::vector<contact_data>` *(or maybe multiple vectors, one per thread)* and then solve all the contacts sequentially in a later step. After solving all contacts, the vector(s) can be `clear`ed.

Comment: Hi.Every time step the contact list needs to be updated because of the system dynamics, and not only some new contacts are created while some others are destroyed, but also there contacts themselves evolved since, for example, the relative displacement between particles changed. A typical simulation requires over million of steps. Clearing the whole list every time step would be prohibitively expensive in terms of performance